# trigger function after each Jquery

Tags: jquery, each, settimeout, setinterval

```
    var delay = 0;
    var interval = 1000;
    var reload = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.bl').each(function(i){ 
            $(this).delay(delay).animate({
                height: '150px'
            },500);
            delay += interval;
        });
    },interval);

setInterval(reload,delay);
```

Hi folks, can't hide all the blocks after all of them appear.

Comment: This appears a little overkill... Please describe the end effect you are aiming for (a sample of the HTML would be nice for a solution mockup)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie yes, im creating html banner :) and want to loop the function, the function itself shows blocks one by one, then after all the blocks are visible, i want them to become again height 0  at once, then function repeats.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense... back soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using no timers, just the animation promises returned from each element's animation queue:

```
 var interval = 1000;
 var reload = function () {
     var delay = 0;
     var promise;   // "Undefined" equates to an initial resolved promise
     $('.bl').css({
         height: 0
     }).each(function (i) {
         // chain promises in parallel using repeated $.when calls
         promise = $.when(promise, $(this).delay(delay).animate({
             height: '150px'
         }).promise());
         delay += interval;
     });
     // When all animation promises complete, start the process pseudo-recursively
     promise.then(reload);
 }
 reload();
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/rtuLzc6t/

The only sneaky bit is my chaining of promises in parallel using `promise = $.when(promise, newpromise)`. The end result of the loop is a single promise that completes when all the animations end. The final `then` makes it recurse.